# Jboss Standard Out Timestamp

Tags: java, logging, jboss

When I start up my JBoss server I pipe standard out to a file.  When looking at that file I see a timestamp but I can't figure out what day the event happend.

The sample below is from my output file.  I can see the action happened at 10:35 but on what day and what does the "24,253" mean?

```
 10:35:24,253 INFO  [STDOUT] Here 1 
 10:35:24,253 INFO  [STDOUT] Here 2 
 10:35:24,254 INFO  [STDOUT] Here 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 10:35:24 is the time (24 is seconds) and 253/254 is milliseconds.  To see the full date, check the logs that JBoss generates (mine are in ...\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\log\server.log).

Answer (score 1):

The logging configuration for the stdout logging in JBoss omits the date, as you've noticed. However, the stdout logging only lasts long enough for JBoss to fully reconfigure log4j, at which point most logging to stdout will stop. The remaining logs are then stored in the log directory, and have full date and time stamped records.

It's worth noting that any applications which use stdout/stderr should get those records written both to the piped stdout/strerr streams, as well as to the log4j log files. Anything in the piped streams should also appear in the full log files. If it's not, then it can be configured to do so.

Comment: I do know about the log files and should start using them.  I was just wondering.  Thanks.